# Persian speech to text in android

Tags: android, speech-to-text, persian, sound-recognition

i want to improve my knowledge and work with sound reorganization (speech to text). i find good samples from google but i don't know how can i do so with Persian-Farsi language? i do it with English but how about Farsi? is it need some setting in my mobile android phone? is there anyone who do so?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 7):

just put new extra in your intent as below

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "fa");
```